# Wiping SD card won't work

Tags: sd-card

I'm trying to wipe my sd card because I want to completely start over with my raspi. I tried wiping it with gparted but somehow after every modification I try to make on it, it remains the same afterwards. I just tried wiping it with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=8192` but once it was done it gave me a

```
dd: error writing '/dev/mmcblk0': No space left on device
1955713+0 records in
1955712+0 records out
1621192704 bytes (16 GB) copied, 408,205 s, 39,2 MB/s
```

What's going on here and more importantly? How do I actually wipe this thing?

EDIT 1: I don't know if this is relevant, but I might just mention it as well. GParted doesn't detect my regular ssd, but only the sd-card.

Comment: Why do you want to *wipe* the device. Just repartition it. This method of wiping does nothing more than waste write cycles.

Comment: Repartitioning it would be fine too, but it doesn't work either (tried it through gparted). So I thought I'd go with the more thorough method.

Comment: Try using minitool parition wizard, I use it all the time, it works great at removing the partition Windows can't see. You can then create a new partition that is the full size of the SD card. DO NOT REPEAT WIPE YOUR SD CARD. It is a sure fire way of reducing its lifespan.

Comment: If you are trying to do this kind of thing with card in the pi it won't work.

Comment: It is not possible to modify a mounted filesystem, on the Pi or any other Linux system. If you are installing Raspbian there is no need (and no point). Raspbian is a disk image and will overwrite the existing. You only need a clean card to install NOOBS.

Comment: Minitool partition wizard won't work: I'm on Linux. I'm formatting it from my laptop, not my pi, so that's not the problem either. And I do unmount the filesystem before trying to repartition/format it, but that still doesn't affect it. I tried installing the raspbian image on the sd-card with dd, but it didn't overwrite the existing image, that's where the entire problem started.

Answer (score 1):

You are already successfully wiping the card. You didn't include a count= in the dd command - so it will keep on going until you have written zeros to every block on the target device  as /dev/zero is infinite in size.

Comment: I'm quite sure I'm not wiping successfully, because when I check the card afterwards, it still has all the files on there.